# Find the equation of the plane passing through the three points $P_1 = (1, 2, - 1)$, $P_2 = ( - 1, 1, 4)$, $P_3 = (1,3, -2)$.

Tags: linear-algebra

The equation of the plane is $N \cdot (X - P) = 0$ where $X$ and $P$ are the points on the plane and $N$ is the normal to the plane.

What goes wrong when we do something like this below:

$P_3 - P_1 = (-2, -1, 5)$

Let $N = (a, b, c)$

$N \cdot (P_3 - P_1) = - 2a - b + 5c =0$.

So, $N =(a, b, c) = (1, 3, 1)$ satisfies the equation above.

Then, $(1,3, 1) \cdot (x, y, z) = (-2, -2, 5) \cdot (1, 3, 1)$

Thus, $x + 3y + z = -2 - 6 + 5 = -3$.

Answer (score 1):

You need a vector $N$ that is perpendicular to both $P_3-P_1$ and $P_2-P_1$, not just one of them.

Hint: What do you know about the cross product of two vectors?

Comment: To be honest, I got the solution of it in my textbook written out in full. I was just wondering why just one vector on the plane perpendicular to $N$ is not sufficient. Isnt $N$ perpendicular to all vectors on the plane if it's perpendicular to at least one of them? It's from Serge Lang's book. He doesn't cover cross product.

Comment: In $\mathbb{R}^3$, for a given vector $P_3-P_1$, you can find infinitely many vectors $N$ that are perpendicular to $P_3-P_1$. Remember, $3$ points determine a plane, only $2$ do not.

Comment: Is it true, then, $X \cdot N = -2a -b + 5c = 0$ and $P \cdot N = b - c = 0 $?

Comment: No, but it is true that $N \cdot (P_2 - P_1) = 0$ and that $N \cdot (P_3-P_1) = 0$.

Comment: In the equation $X \cdot N = P \cdot N$ there's only one $P$, but how do we know we need 2 more to find the equation of the plane?

Comment: Why do you think we can determine the equation of a plane using only two of the three points provided?

Comment: Suppose I only used one  point and it didnt work. How would I know I need 2 more going solely by $X \cdot N = P \cdot N$? This is what I really want to understand.